# Applying multiple ForegroundColorSpan

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

I want to apply `ForegroundColorSpan` to multiple words in a given string.

However, only the last applied span is taking effect.

My code is:

```
private fun formatString(target: String, vararg formattableWords: String): SpannableString {
    val spannableString = SpannableString(target)

    val colorSpan = ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))

    formattableWords.forEach { formattableWord ->
        val start = target.indexOf(formattableWord, ignoreCase = true)
        val end = start + formattableWord.length

        spannableString.setSpan(colorSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }

    return spannableString
}
```

When I call it in the following code:

```
entryTermsConditionsPrivacy.text = formatString(
            "By using APP you agree to the Terms and Conditions and the Privacy Policy.",
            "APP", "Terms and Conditions", "Privacy Policy"
        )
```

Only `Privacy Policy` receives the applied `ForegroundColorSpan`

Comment: Why are you using a single span instance for all words and not creating a new span inside the forEach lambda for each of the words?

Comment: @Luksprog I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you will need new object of `ForegroundColorSpan`

```
private fun formatString(target: String, vararg formattableWords: String): SpannableString {
val spannableString = SpannableString(target)

//    val colorSpan = ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))

formattableWords.forEach { formattableWord ->
  val start = target.indexOf(formattableWord, ignoreCase = true)
  val end = start + formattableWord.length

  spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
}

return spannableString
}
```